# UI not updating stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently running into issuse with updating my stateless widget. Is there something I am missing. As basicaly when I click on the icon in the widget, I want it to remove both the data from the list and update UI, so the Icon data no longer shows

```
Future<void> _removeIncluded(BuildContext context) async {
for (int i = 0; i < includedList.length; i++) {
  print(includedList[i].title);
  print(title);
  if (includedList[i].title == this.title) {
    includedList.remove(includedList[i]);
    included.remove(this.title);
    // includedList.removeAt(i);
    // included.removeAt(i);
  }
}
rebuildAllChildren(context);
```

}

```
 void rebuildAllChildren(BuildContext context) {
void rebuild(Element el) {
  el.markNeedsBuild();
  el.visitChildren(rebuild);
}

(context as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
```

}

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.5),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xffDEDEDE), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Row(
            //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                  title.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular", fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close_outlined, size: 20),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _removeIncluded(context);
                  })
            ]),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: We can use `StatefulWidget` and `setState` function

Comment: @Mardel do you have any code sample or  more pointers to put me in the right direction as I am very new to dartxflutter

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive